# Creating Facebook event with an image via Spring social

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

Looking over the spring social facebook api, EventOperations offers

```
    createEvent(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String startTime, 
                                                      java.lang.String endTime)
```

to post Events to facebook.

Is there a way to post more information for the event, like event image and event description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `createEvent` method, it does not currently support the attachment (event image). It does however call into GraphApi `publish` to actually publish the event:

```
public String createEvent(String name, String startTime, String endTime) {
    requireAuthorization();
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    data.set("name", name);
    data.set("start_time", startTime);
    data.set("end_time", endTime);
    return graphApi.publish("me", "events", data);
}
```

`graphApi`.publish(...) itself ( which is implemented in [FacebookTemplate](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-facebook/blob/master/spring-social-facebook/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/impl/FacebookTemplate.java) ) would support *anything* as a {key,value} pair that Facebook is ready to accept, as it just delegates to the RestTemplate, and feeds all the {key,value} pairs to Facebook through a regular HTTP POST:

```
public String publish(String objectId, String connectionType, MultiValueMap<String, Object> data) {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>(data);
    URI uri = URIBuilder.fromUri(GRAPH_API_URL + objectId + "/" + connectionType).build();
    Map<String, Object> response = getRestTemplate().postForObject(uri, requestData, Map.class);
    return (String) response.get("id");
}
```

Hence you can extend the [EventTemplate](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-facebook/blob/master/spring-social-facebook/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/impl/EventTemplate.java) and add another `createEvent` method, that would take an `image name` and an `image file path`, and would added it as an additional {key,value} to a `data` MultiMap:

```
data.set( "@" + imageName, "@" + imagePath )
```

Hence the method would look close to:

```
public String createEvent( String name, 
                           String startTime, 
                           String endTime,
                           String imageName,
                           String imagePath ) {   // or maybe even "File image", where you would derive the path
    requireAuthorization();
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    data.set("name", name);
    data.set("start_time", startTime);
    data.set("end_time", endTime);

    data.set( "@" + imageName, "@" + imagePath );  // <<< adding this line

    return graphApi.publish("me", "events", data);
}
```

This of course does not include any possible validation that you might want to do, etc..
Once you have this working, which seems to be pretty straightforward, you can donate / contribute it back to Spring Social => they'd be very pleased :)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation. I am playing with it right now but having some problems with actual image, any other event information gets published but not image ... investigating it further

Comment: are you sure your `imagePath` is correct? do you see any problems / exceptions?

Comment: all is correct, I initiate File and do absolutePath just in case

Comment: also based on what I am reading it prob going to be: data.set( "picture", "@" + imagePath );

Comment: Ok finally, I got it, going to edit your example to make it work

Comment: I had to use org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResourceFileSystemResource with data.set("picture", resource)

Answer (score 0):

Although answer provided was possibly correct at the time, nowadays this answer is misleading and wrong. Since v2.1 onwards you **can't do CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE** of Events via API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/